# What’s the process of checking insects when making wine

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization, yoreh-deah, chulin-tractate

BH

What’s the process checking for insects when making wine? Is there any videos on this and where does it talk about this in Shulchan Aruch And Halacha?

Comment: I don't think people check for insects when eating grapes, at least in America. Presumably that means they are not known to have a problem.